# How to preserve the state of jquery ui sortable interactions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>


<div class="demo">

   <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

When i first load page, the list is in this(first pic below) order(1 through to 7), then i move and change the order of the list(second pic below). Hit reload and the order reverts back to the original order. **Is is possible to preserve the changed order of the lists.**

[image]

[image]

thank you for the help

Comment: i think u will need to set a cookie or work with db results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a question about how to store data in between page refreshes. It's not something specific to jQuery UI. There are generally two main places you can store the necessary data:

1) A cookie
2) A database

If you want to maintain the order of the lists in the long-term, then you will need to use a database. If it's just a short-term issue, then a cookie is likely the better of the two solutions because it's a lot simpler and won't require a bunch of AJAX requests.

HTML5 also offers local data storage, so you could accomplish the same thing with that. But it won't be supported by all browsers.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, i definitely plan on long-term storage in a db, just one problem though, i have intermediate skills with ajax and jquery, could you point me to a good starting point on how i can approach this as i have seen some blogs and sites where this has been done through php and jquery, but not with rails so i did get a bit confused with the code. thanks

Comment: cool, thanks for the info though. Will keep looking to find out how to do this.